# how to delete database row React js .net core?

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using visual studio 2022 react js web app with .net core template. I  am able to insert and show data but can't figure out how to use delete .in react js component i have function that calls on button click:

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure to delete this employee") == true) {
        alert(id)
        fetch(`/api/product/DeleteProduct/${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            header: {
                'Accept': 'Application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'Application/json'
            }
        }).then(result => { result.json.then((resp) => { console.warn(resp) }) })
            
    }

}
```

and in ProductController I have:

```
public IActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
        {

            NavbaseContext db = new NavbaseContext();
            Product existingProduct = db.Products.Where(temp => temp.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();    
            
            
                db.Products.Remove(existingProduct);
                db.SaveChanges(); 
                     
            return (RedirectToAction("getProducts"));

        }
```

Comment: You don't seem to pass the ID to .Net. You `alert(id)` but never attach it to your fetch request.

Comment: ive tried this :   fetch(`/api/product/DeleteProduct/${id}`, , didn't work

Comment: What route have you configured for `DeleteProduct`, have you breakpointed to check the ID is coming through?

Comment: You should also have the `[HttpDelete]` attribute applied to your request, I don't know if this is omitted from your snippet or missing altogether.

Comment: i checked console, it gives error 404 not found . https://localhost:44408/api/product/DeleteProduct/12   : 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This would mean it's not finding your route from .Net, probably because it hasn't been configured as you except it to be automatically. Routes will most likely be defined either when building your app in `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` or as an attribute on the controller or the request method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should update your URL to adapt restful URL

```
httpmethod:delete

url:http://localhost:5000/api/proudcts/1
```